# When accessing properties of an object in an array through a loop, only getting the first element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, socket.io

It is a bit hard for me to put my problem into a one-liner Title, so here is the deal. I have two functions on an object. These are:

```
returnPlayers: function() {
    return this.players;
},
```

and

```
returnPlayerNames: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
        return this.players[i].name;
    }
}
```

The output of the first one is:

`[ Player {
    socket:
     Socket {
       nsp: [Object],
       server: [Object],
       adapter: [Object],
       id: 'CyrH8LGDRtmaWWUzAAAD',
       client: [Object],
       conn: [Object],
       rooms: [Object],
       acks: {},
       connected: true,
       disconnected: false,
       handshake: [Object],
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 3 },
    name: 'Foo',
    score: 0 },
  Player {
    socket:
     Socket {
       nsp: [Object],
       server: [Object],
       adapter: [Object],
       id: 'nCCYjPFfkd1JaSDXAAAC',
       client: [Object],
       conn: [Object],
       rooms: [Object],
       acks: {},
       connected: true,
       disconnected: false,
       handshake: [Object],
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 3 },
    name: 'Bar',
    score: 0 } ]`

We can clearly see, that there are two objects in the array. The output of the second one (which should only return names) is only the name of the first object however: `Foo`

What am I doing wrong? The output is from `console.log()` ofc.

Comment: `return` causes a function to end even if the for loop hasn't finished. Put all the names into an array and return that after the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `return`, the function ends. The rest of the for loop won't run. Here's what you have to do.

```
returnPlayerNames: function() {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
        output.push(this.players[i].name);
    }
    return output;
}
```

This will make a new array and add the names of each player to it. Someday, whenever ES7 gets going, we'll be able to do this in one line, like in Python.

```
return [player.name for player in players]
```

The future's going to be pretty cool. But until then, the first thing I said will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays map method

```
returnPlayerNames: function() {
  return this.players.map(function(player) { return player.name })
}
```